# Mat error - "unfortunately the app could not load" in android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am running a java script for canny edge detection, and when I use the keyword Mat anywhere in the program, or even the other Mat variables, the app is not loading.How can I resolve this.

The code I am using is the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Mat m;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click);
        final String    TAG             = "OCVSample::Activity";

        BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
            @Override
            public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                switch (status) {
                    case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                        m=new Mat();

                    } break;
                    default:
                    {
                        super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    } break;
                }
            }
       };
       ImageView imageSource=null,imageAfter = null; 
       Bitmap source=null,result = null;
       imageSource = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       source=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.strips1);
       Mat matSource = null;
       // Handle initialization error
       Utils.bitmapToMat(source, matSource);
       Mat matResult = null;
       Imgproc.Canny(matSource, matResult, 80, 90);
       Utils.matToBitmap(matResult,result);
       imageAfter.setImageBitmap(result);
```

Comment: You resolve this by reading LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use opencv code *after* BaseLoaderCallback finished ( and the dll's/so's were loaded ).

so, doing the Canny code in onCreate won't work ( it's too early for that ).

either move it after the LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: or to onCameraViewStarted() or similar

(btw, this only got obvious after applying some work on your *horribly* formatted code ... )